# Scriban , how to use something else then "{{" "}}"

Tags: c#, scriban

I'm trying to use Scriban in a C# code to replace some place holders in my text file,
but my text file contain "{{" and "}}" already, is there anyway to use some custom delimiters ?

thank you in advance

Comment: seems like No. https://github.com/scriban/scriban/issues/512